# Intermittent SSL certificate verification failures with mechanize and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, openssl, mechanize

I have a Rails 3.2.8 app, with Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 12.04. It uses mechanize to connect to an https web site.

I am seeing this error intermittently:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I do set the CA file:

```
Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.ssl_version = "SSLv3"
  agent.ca_file = Rails.root.join("lib/cacert.pem").to_s
end
```

I have also tried using `cert_store`:

```
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
cert_store.set_default_paths

Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.ssl_version = "SSLv3"
  agent.cert_store = cert_store
end
```

And setting the store explicitly:

```
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
cert_store.add_file Rails.root.join("lib/cacert.pem").to_s

Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.ssl_version = "SSLv3"
  agent.cert_store = cert_store
end
```

These errors appear regardless of which method I use to specify the CA/certificates (including relying on default behaviour). When I run the code manually from rails console, it works fine. Which of the above, if any, are correct? What else can I do to debug this?